# How to replace words in multiples files

Tags: python, replace

I have 19 files where one region-`CHLB` is written in some places. I have to make copies of these 19 files for another regions - replace , for example, `STORE` to `CHLB`
I wrote some code but Im stuck. Help me please!

```
fin = open("data.txt", "rt")
data = fin.read()
data = data.replace('pyton', 'python')
fin.close()

fin = open("data.txt", "wt")
fin.write(data)
fin.close()
```

Comment: u can use notepad plus plus to replace it

Comment: What's wrong with the code you wrote?

Comment: Also, maybe you can share an example of your input and the desired output

Answer (score 0):

Although you can use the `sed` command or text editors to do this, I think this is what you're looking for in python

```
fin = open('data.txt','r+')
data = fin.read()
data = data.replace('pyton','python')
fin.seek(0)
fin.truncate()
fin.write(data)
fin.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

````
texttofind='CHLB'

texttoreplace='EKAT'

sourcepath = os.listdir('C:\\GIT\\sandbox\\airflow\\dags\\tst\\Queries\\')

for file in sourcepath:
    inputfile='C:\\GIT\\sandbox\\airflow\\dags\\tst\\Queries\\'+file
    print('Conversion in ongoing for: ' + inputfile)

    with open(inputfile,'r') as inputfile:
        filedata=inputfile.read()
        freq=0
        fred=filedata.count(texttofind)

    destinationpath='C:\\GIT\\sandbox\\airflow\\dags\\tst\\Queries\\' + file
    filedata=filedata.replace(texttofind,texttoreplace)

    with open(destinationpath, 'w') as file:
        file.write()```
````